# How to build sml3d from svn?

Tags: opengl, build-process, sml, smlnj, mlton

I'm trying to build the [sml3d](http://sml3d.cs.uchicago.edu/index.html) from the SVN source (is there an another way?).

First, checked out the source with the following command like below:

```
$svn co --username anonsvn \
  https://smlnj-gforge.cs.uchicago.edu/svn/sml3d/trunk sml3d
```

Then, I read sml3d/README 'BUILDING FROM SVN' section and tried like ...

```
$autoheader -Iconfig
$autoconf -Iconfig
$./configure
```

At this point, I got these many errors...

> ```
> (snip)
> make[1]: Entering directory `/home/eldesh/work/sml3d/sml3d/gen/fi-gen'
> cc     gen-sdl-offsets.c   -o gen-sdl-offsets
> /tmp/ccmu83YP.o: In function `main':
> gen-sdl-offsets.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to `prField'
> gen-sdl-offsets.c:(.text+0xcd): undefined reference to `prField'
> gen-sdl-offsets.c:(.text+0xe9): undefined reference to `prField'
> gen-sdl-offsets.c:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `prField'
> gen-sdl-offsets.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `prField'
> /tmp/ccmu83YP.o:gen-sdl-offsets.c:(.text+0x13d): more undefined references to `prField' follow
> /tmp/ccmu83YP.o: In function `main':
> gen-sdl-offsets.c:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `prConst'
>
> blah blah blah...
> ```

Next, I guess the correct building protocol like below:

```
$autoheader -Iconfig
$autoconf -Iconfig
$./configure --enable-dev
$mkdir -p src/sml3d/opengl/c-abi
$cd gen/gen-from-xml/specs
$make
$../../../bin/glgen  targets.json
$../../../bin/grpgen targets.json
```

But I got not-exists and Undefined errors yet:

> ```
> ~/sml3d/sml3d$ make
> (snip)
> make[2]: Entering directory `/home/eldesh/work/sml3d/sml3d/src/sml3d'
> /home/eldesh/lcl/bin/mlton -mlb-path-var 'GL_DIR gl32' -stop tc sml3d.mlb
> Error: opengl/opengl-32.mlb 45.3.
>   File gl-object-fn.sml does not exist.
> Error: gl32/gl32-types.sml 8.26.
>   Undefined functor GLObjectFn.
> (snip)
> Error: gl32/frame-buffer.sml 11.14.
>   Undefined structure FramebufObj.
> Error: gl32/frame-buffer.sml 13.25.
>   Undefined structure RenderbufObj.
> (snip)
> Error: gl32/frame-buffer.sml 7.27.
>   Type texture_id in signature but not in structure.
> Error: gl32/frame-buffer.sml 60.14.
> ...
> ```

How to build sml3d correctly ?

#### environment

I use runtime/systems...

- smlnj 110.77
- mlton 20130715
- linux x86